Download SharePoint Custom Form (Power Apps)
I want to download a SPO custom form via Powershell.
I´ve tried command below but get an error message, which says there is no canvas app in this enviroment which is the default enviroment. A download of a regular canvas apps works fine.
pac canvas download  --name 'CustomFormSource on CustomFormMigration forms'  --extract-to-directory C:\Users\xxxx\OneDrive\Skript\Form
Any ideas?

As far as I have tested, pac does not support the management of custom form canvas apps. Executing pac canvas list also won't show any custom forms.
